# It is a $G$−equivalent homorphisms

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V,W$ be 2 $G$-representations, with $W$ irreducible. We observe the following map:
$$d_W: Hom_G(W,V) \otimes W \to V, \;\;\phi \otimes w \mapsto \phi(w)$$
The goal is to show that $d_W$ is a $G-$equivalent homorphisms. The proof is given as follow:

$$d_W(g(\phi \otimes w))=d_W(g(\phi) \otimes g(w))=g(\phi)(g(w))=g(\phi(g^{-1}(g(w)))=g(\phi(w))=g(d_W(\phi \otimes w))\;\; \forall g \in G$$
Where $Hom_G(V,W):=\{f:V \to W\; | \;\text{$f$ is a $G$-equivalent Homorphism}\}$.

I don't understand now the point: $$g(\phi)(g(w))=g(\phi(g^{-1}(g(w)))$$ How can we conclude that? Many thanks for some helps!

Comment: For $g \in G$ and $\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}(W,V)$, the function $g(\phi) : W \to V$ is **defined** by $x \mapsto g(\phi(g^{-1}(x)))$.

Comment: Indeed, many thanks!